# Python: How to save timedelta to MySQL

Tags: python-3.x

I want to save the duration of a job in python3.x and save it to MySQL 5.7 time field.

```
datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 16, 15, 36, 52, 132454)
```

returns:

```
datetime.timedelta(seconds=7635, microseconds=282960)
```

How do I retrieve the seconds from this output in order to put them into my MySQL statement?

Comment: `datetime.timedelta(seconds=7635, microseconds=282960).total_seconds()`

Comment: seems not to work. I am getting  00:00:00 in my time field with insert:                     (datetime.datetime.now() -  stats['start_time']).total_seconds(),

Comment: right, I removed the .total_seconds() now it works in my time field. Just have to find out why there is a time offset of 2 hours now :-)

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the last part of your question then. My mistake.

Comment: I wonder if you can use the MySQL SEC_TO_TIME() function here.

Comment: No prob. Do you know why python is offsetting me 2h? System clock is OK: datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 16, 15, 58, 36, 623143). Must be somehow a time zone setting.

Comment: I'm not sure. It doesn't look like your value has a timezone, and now() doesn't return a datetime with a timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this to avoid the timezone issue you're seeing:

```
import datetime as dt
import mysql.connector

total_seconds = dt.timedelta(seconds=7635, microseconds=282960).total_seconds()

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='username', database='your_database')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO your_table 
                      (your_time_field) 
                  VALUES (SEC_TO_TIME(%s));""",(total_seconds,))
```

Comment: Thank you that works. I went to saving UTC now as it seems to be recommended for saving within DBs

Comment: You're welcome. UTC now seems like it would've also solved the issue.